# JpaRepository.getOne confusion

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, aop

I am working on a big project which uses spring framework where I have a service like this:

```
  @Component
  public class ExampleService{

       @Autowired
       ChildOfJpaRepository childOfJpaRepository;

       public void fetchAndSet(ExampleParentEntity exampleParentEntity,Long id){
          exampleParentEntity.setChildEntity(childOfJpaRepository.getOne(id));
       }
  }
```

`ChildOfJpaRepository` is a repository interface which extends `JpaRepository` (from org.springframework.data.jpa.repository package). `ExampleParentEntity` is just some DB entity which has a field `ExampleChildEntity` and a setter. When I call `childOfJpaRepository.getOne(id)` I expect to get a proxy of `ExampleChildEntity` . However, it turns out my `childOfJpaRepository` is wrapped in `JdkDynamicAopProxy`. When method `getOne` is executed it invokes `TransactionInterceptor` and after a while creates a transaction. Here is a full stack trace of what is happening after `getOne` is executed (it is not an error stack trace, but simply what is happening after `getOne` is triggered):

> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1092.getOne() 
>       org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke()
>           org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
>               org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke() 
>                   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
>                       org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke()
>                           org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
>                               org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke() 
>                                   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction()
>                                       org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary()
>                                       org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning()
>                                       org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation()

My problem is that because the transaction is getting created, insted of fetching proxy of `ExampleChildEntity`, I actually get `ExampleChildEntity` (and I want a proxy). From my analisys it seem that I have a problem with Aspect Oriented Programming configurations. How can I turn off this `JdkDynamicAopProxy` wrapping or how can I change it's behaviour (I don't want for it to invoke transaction creation)?

Comment: does ChildOfJpaRepository perhaps override getOne behaviour?

Comment: Here's the implementation of getOne(): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/476baa480912f5e239905da0172fae1faba1d902/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L247-L256. So unless you overrode it, all it does is calling getReference(), and there is thus no reason that is behaves in a different way.

Comment: @Zeromus unfortunately not

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my question.

Comment: Why did you cut off the actual error message from the stacktrace? And where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The stacktrace clearly shows that some transaction aspect thing is going on, which contradicts your own statement that there is no such thing in your code. Without the MCVE probably nobody can help you.

Comment: @kriegaex - I observe this stacktrace in jvisualvm so there is no error message. It is just an observation how the code executes. I also only state that in my code "There seem to be no Transactional annotation in the fetchAndSet call hierarchy nor any transaction configurations other than annotation-driven". You have to understand that I am clearly new to AOP and did not know much about it before the problem occurs and hours of debugging.

Comment: And you have to understand that professional developers spending their free time in order to help others like to give advice based on facts, not on pure guesswork. So it does not matter if you are new to AOP or not. Provide a reproduceable problem description or - with all due respect - solve your problem alone. If you can observe a stacktrace via VisualVM, probably you can also see the corresponding error somewhere on the server's console or log files. If there are no errors, then what is your problem? An MCVE would show what happens and you could say what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: @kriegaex - Fair point. I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Ofcourse your repository is a proxy as that is how it is being implemented at runtime. So no you cannot disable this unless you want to remove Spring Data JPA. I also doubt the issue is actually with the `getOne` call (you haven't posted the full stacktrace just a snippet).